# How to get incident details using BMC Remedy REST API Authentication?

Tags: rest, remedy

I have used to get authenticate to BMC Remedy to get incident via below url:

```
 https:<host>:<port>/api/jwt/login
```

with username and password as a parameter and content-type as url-form encoded... But I got an error

```
[
  {
    "messageType": "ERROR",
    "messageNumber": 8790,
    "messageText": "Unknown system error",
    "appendedText": "HTTP 400 Bad Request"
   }
]
```

Currently i am working on developer sandbox instance.. After I created the sandbox .I got the details to my mail like

Product:Innovation Studio

Host: developerxxx.innovate.bmc.com

AR Java API Port:   46200

Innovation Studio URL:  https://developerxxxx.innovate.bmc.com/com.bmc.arsys.rx.innovationstudio/index.html

Mid Tier URL:   https://developerxxxx.innovate.bmc.com:8443/arsys

Field ID Range: 10445xx1:10446xx0

I need to get incident details using BMC Remedy REST API Authentication.